# Unmount USB Camera

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I'm working in a Python app with opencv and a USB camera. Sometimes the camera driver throws an exception:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3650

or a Segmentation Fault.

I think it's because of the camera driver. The camera stops working after that (though the camera light remains on) and I need to disconnect and reconnect it.

Is there a way to unmount and then remount that Camera with Python?  Or is there an alternative way to fix this?

(I've searched on /media and /mnt, and I could not find the camera there).

This is my code:

```
self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, camerapicshowwidth)
self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, camerapicshowheight)
while updateCamera:
    _, frame = self.cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    img.thumbnail((showpicsmallwidth, showpicsmallheight),Image.BILINEAR);
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    self.cameraLabel.imgtk = imgtk
    self.cameraLabel.configure(image=imgtk)
```

Comment: You should add a check `if frame.empty()` and if it returns false, you should proceed to process the frame. It's been noted that once camera is opened, it takes certain amount of time (probably a few hundred ms) before it could actually capture frames. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried but i got this error:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'empty'